# How to inject a list of attributes as a string in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am writing a React component that makes my text editable. When clicked, it renders an input, when blurred it renders a text like before.

To make it work, I have to put a lot of attributes in my elements. I want to handle many types of inputs (text, number, date, textarea, ...) and I don't want to repeat this list all along.

Is there a way of writing this list only once and inject it in my elements?

Something like this:

```
const options = "value={this.props.value} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} onChange={this.props.onChange}  onBlur={this.stopEdit} ref={(e) => {this.eRef = e;}}";
```

Later used like that:

```
render() {
    return (<input type="text" {{options}} />);
}
```

I have read about [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) but that's not doing what I need.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you dont use like this

```
const options = {
  value: this.props.value,
  placeholder: this.props.placeholder,
  ...
}
```

and `html = <input type="text" {...options}/>`

or you can use

```
html = React.createElement('input', {type: 'text', ...options})
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking on how to make text in your element editable, perhaps attach the `content-editable="true"` attribute to the element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's useful, thanks. But I want to control how it is edited so I stick to my homemade component :)